# Create a pagination on a table with filters with php/SQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, filter, pagination

I'd like to create a pagination on a table which have a filter per column, I found it on bootsnipp, and I adapted it on my code.
I had tested several library to make pagination on this table but the results it's not what I expect.

I'd like a table with 10 row at first with the pagination, and the filter button transform the table's header in input with a research in jquery.

Do you think it's possible to combine both?
When I clic on the filter's button I can write only one letter and it close it.

The table's code with filter: https://jsfiddle.net/Mallarky/a9tn4n5o/1/

This is the code I found of pagination from ZebraPagination https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Pagination :

```
    <?php

// how many records should be displayed on a page?
$records_per_page = 10;

// include the pagination class
require 'path/to/Zebra_Pagination.php';

// instantiate the pagination object
$pagination = new Zebra_Pagination();

// the MySQL statement to fetch the rows
// note how we build the LIMIT
// also, note the "SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS"
// this is to get the number of rows that would've been returned if there was no LIMIT
$sql = '
    SELECT
        SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
        country
    FROM
        countries
    LIMIT
        ' . (($pagination->get_page() - 1) * $records_per_page) . ', ' . $records_per_page . '
';

// execute the MySQL query
// (you will use mysqli or PDO here, but you get the idea)
$result = mysql_query($sql))) or die(mysql_error());

// fetch the total number of records in the table
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS rows'));

// pass the total number of records to the pagination class
$pagination->records($rows['rows']);

// records per page
$pagination->records_per_page($records_per_page);

?>

<table>
    <tr><th>Country</th></tr>
    <?php $index = 0; while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)):?>
    <tr<?php echo $index++ % 2 ? ' class="even"' : ''; ?>>
        <td><?php echo $row['country']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>

<?php

// render the pagination links
$pagination->render();
```

Is it possible to refresh the table in ajax instead of refreash all the page?
I hope you can help me.
Regards

Comment: Or using ajax to retrieve data on every keyup event

Comment: Why don't you use **Datatables** ? (https://datatables.net/) They are easy to configure and have so many helpful functionalities such as pagination or filters!

Comment: First, thanks for these 2 answers.
I have already DataTable in the app and I have some problems with it, I thought with a simple table it would be better.
I have also a problem with the loading page, it's too slow

Comment: I forgot to precise, I've only these versions :
jquery 1.8.0
dataTable 1.9.1
(and bootstrap v2.1.0)
Of course, I cannot update it